# What're the purposes of these special characters in SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

```
$sel1 = mysql_query ("SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender,
    FROM USERS_TABLE
    WHERE (name = '$user' OR email = '$user') AND pass = '$pass'");

$chk = mysql_fetch_array($sel1);

if (found one record)
then {allow the user to login}`
```

The question is that try to login with username admin');#", then you will find that you logged in as the user admin!
Question asks what each special character purpose in sql injection. 
,
)
;
#
"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value:

```
admin');#
```

would terminate the SQL statement after the string "admin" and treat everything after as a comment.  So this:

```
SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender,
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = '$user' OR email = '$user') AND pass = '$pass'
```

essentially becomes this:

```
SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender,
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = 'admin')
```

A record is found and the system happily continues on its way, having logged the user in as `'admin'` because the query successfully found that record.

Comment: Thank you! But do you know what each specific special character does? Like, comma, right parentheses, semicolon and #?

Comment: @hsnyc: A single-quote is used to wrap string values.  Parentheses are used to enclose things (in this case the `WHERE` clause).  Semi-colon is used to end a statement.  `#` is used to begin a comment.